# How to change image on button after click reactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I have a save button with an image (bordered icon) . I want to change icon color on button click is success

```
const saveClickProperty = () => {
    console.log("test");
    if(userId) {
        setLoading(true);
        propertyUserSave({
            userId: userId,
            propertyId: property._id
        }).then((resp) => {
            console.log("hello");
            openNotification("", "Property Saved");
            if (isSuccess(resp)) {
                console.log("inside");
                openNotification(userMessage.successHeader, userMessage.propertySaved);  
            }
        }).finally(() => setLoading(false));
    }
}
```

and i want to change save.png

```
<div className="saveAction">
                {userId && 
                    <a onClick={saveClickProperty} className="">
                        <div className="ActionDiv">
                            <img src="/images/index/save.png" alt="save" /> {' '} Save
                        </div>
                    </a>
                }

            </div>
```

right now this is look like [image]

Any idea to change save.png image color after button click (i mean when property is successfully saved).

Comment: Can you include the CSS used, i.e. for classes `saveAction` and `ActionDiv`, anything that is styling the button. I don't think you can just "change" the color of a png file, but you may be able to do some filter/overlay. Can you also provide clearer expected result? Is it simply after the button is clicked change the color, or after *some* success state value is updated?

Comment: @DrewReese i want to do like similarly facebook like button is only bordered and after click it filled with color. I want to make my button same , when some one click to save , after success message color of  heart on button must be change with some color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to create a state and after the property is saved, change that state, in order to the components (icon colors and image) re-render.

Example for State:

```
const [success, setSucess] = useState(false);
```

Example for Image:

```
const sucessImage = <img src="/images/index/NEWIMAGE.png" alt="save" />;
const defaultImage = <img src="/images/index/save.png" alt="save" />;

    <div className="saveAction">
                    {userId && 
                        <a onClick={saveClickProperty} className="">
                            <div className="ActionDiv">
                                ${success ? sucessImage : defaultImage} {' '} Save
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    }

                </div>
```

Example of changing the state:

```
...
        }).then((resp) => {
            setSucess(true);
            console.log("hello");
            openNotification("", "Property Saved");
```

Comment: Exactly i was looking for this.